# Regenerate YML mapping issue in Symfony 2.4

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, mapping

Running a Symfony 2 project, I have recently made a change in my MYSQL database, and I would like to update my schema and model structure inside my symfony project so I can use the new items that are in it.

This is what I try to do from a running instance in production:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force CoreBundle yml
```

Here is the error I get:

> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

- Core/Bundle exists and was already mapped this way by the past
- Also note that the server is up and running, doing exchanges with the database
- I cannot find a place where to see a more detailed log. Tried to configure the config.yml to add logging for doctrine but it doesn't give me more infos

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't found the source of the problem, I just deployed a new symfony app, connected it to the database and then just generated orm + entities by following the same commands. After that I just copied the /Entity folder and /orm folder and replaced it on my production env. A bit messy but it worked